# Merge multiple document with different header and footer

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ms-word

I tried merging with

```
Word._Document wordDocument = wordApplication.Documents.Add(
                                              ref templateFileAndPath
                                            , ref missing
                                            , ref missing
                                            , ref missing);

                // Make a Word selection object.
                Word.Selection selection = wordApplication.Selection;

                // Loop thru each of the Word documents
                for (int i = 0; i < filesToMerge.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    string file = filesToMerge[i];
                    if (file != "")
                    {
                        objGenerateDoc.EnqueueAppLog("Merge File " + (i + 1).ToString() + " : " + file.ToString());
                        // Insert the files to our template
                        selection.InsertFile(
                                                    file
                                                , ref missing
                                                , ref missing
                                                , ref missing
                                                , ref missing);

                        //Do we want page breaks added after each documents?
                        if (insertPageBreaks)
                        {                                                        
                            selection.InsertBreak(ref pageBreak);
                        }
                    }
                }

                wordDocument.SaveAs(
                                ref outputFile
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing
                            , ref missing);
```

I do not want to merge header footer format to other page..what do I need to do here? any idea?

**UPDATE**
I tried to do with

```
object DocumentEnd = wordDocument.Content.End - 1;
                        Range InsertRange = wordDocument.Range(ref DocumentEnd, ref DocumentEnd);
                        object wdSectionBreakN = WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage;
                        InsertRange.InsertBreak(ref wdSectionBreakN);
```

still not working..It merge all header footer which I don't want.

Comment: maybe remove header and footer and then merge...

Comment: remove it what? @loneshark99